# Intellij IDEA GIT annotations

Tags: intellij-idea

I right clicked and press Annotate option. It show but I don't see any names but only gray color. How can I fix this?

[image: Screen]

Comment: Was the entire file, by chance, most recently modified in entirety by one commit, and the annotation is at the very top or middle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the wrong color scheme for annotations, there is a chance that text and background have the same color.
Check color settings for annotations in **Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | VCS**

Comment: Thanks, this works. I looked everywhere except there.